# BlobOutputStream alternative in azure-storage-blob version 10.1.0

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am unable to find references of blob output/input stream [BlobOutputStream](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/07fba08e00d3fa29161b8fd9ad0042c5f932cd78/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobOutputStream.java) in azure-storage-blob version 10.1.0 https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java
is it deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a reference package of `azure-storage-blob` version with `maven` and I found the error:

> reference about com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream
>   cannot be resolved.

Then I searched for the class, it shows the highest version which is supported by   `"BlobOutputStream"` is `6.1.0`.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uONm7.png)

So `"BlobOutputStream"` is not supported by `azure-storage-blob v10.`

If you still have questions, please comment me.

Comment: If my answer could help you, could you accept my answer.Thanks.